# How to run sql query using apache camel sqlComponent

Tags: java, apache-camel

Hi I am new to apache camel framework (so most probobly the code I wrote is really bad :) ). I want to connect to my local database and run the sql query and then show up the results in consol. So far I have this:

```
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import org.apache.camel.CamelContext;
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
import org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext;
import org.apache.camel.impl.SimpleRegistry;
import org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource;

public class sqlENEIA3 {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
            String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:ENETEST";
            DataSource dataSource = setupDataSource(url);

            SimpleRegistry reg = new SimpleRegistry();
            reg.put("myDataSource",dataSource);
            CamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext(reg);    
            context.addRoutes(new sqlENEIA3().new MyRouteBuilder());


            context.start();
            Thread.sleep(5000);
            context.stop();

        }


          class MyRouteBuilder extends RouteBuilder {


            public void configure() {
            from("timer://Timer?period=60000").to("sql:select * from projects").to("stream:out");


            }
          } 

        private static DataSource setupDataSource(String connectURI) {
            BasicDataSource ds = new BasicDataSource();
            ds.setDriverClassName("org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"); 
            ds.setUsername("System");
            ds.setPassword("Igor_1");
            ds.setUrl(connectURI);
            return ds;
    }
  }
```

The error message I get is this:

```
250 [main] INFO org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext - Apache Camel     2.16.3 (CamelContext: camel-1) is starting
260 [main] INFO org.apache.camel.management.ManagedManagementStrategy - JMX is enabled
492 [main] INFO org.apache.camel.impl.converter.DefaultTypeConverter -        Loaded 186 type converters
542 [main] INFO org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultRuntimeEndpointRegistry -   Runtime endpoint registry is in extended mode gathering usage statistics of all   incoming and outgoing endpoints (cache limit: 1000)
632 [main] INFO org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext - Apache Camel   2.16.3 (CamelContext: camel-1) is shutting down
642 [main] INFO org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext - Apache Camel 2.16.3 (CamelContext: camel-1) uptime 0.382 seconds
642 [main] INFO org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext - Apache Camel 2.16.3 (CamelContext: camel-1) is shutdown in 0.000 seconds
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.camel.FailedToCreateRouteException:   Failed to create route route1 at: >>> To[sql:select * from projects] <<< in   route: Route(route1)[[From[timer://Timer?period=60000]] -> [To[sql:... because   of Failed to resolve endpoint: sql://select%20*%20from%20projects due to:   DataSource must be configured
at   org.apache.camel.model.RouteDefinition.addRoutes(RouteDefinition.java:1072)
    at   org.apache.camel.model.RouteDefinition.addRoutes(RouteDefinition.java:196)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.startRoute(DefaultCamelContext.java:944)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.startRouteDefinitions(DefaultCamelContext.java:3260)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doStartCamel(DefaultCamelContext.java:2983)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.access$000(DefaultCamelContext.java:175)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext$2.call(DefaultCamelContext.java:2814)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext$2.call(DefaultCamelContext.java:2810)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doWithDefinedClassLoader(DefaultCamelContext.java:2833)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doStart(DefaultCamelContext.java:2810)
    at org.apache.camel.support.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:61)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.start(DefaultCamelContext.java:2779)
    at com.ericsson.custom.opl.sqlENEIA3.main(sqlENEIA3.java:30)
    Caused by: org.apache.camel.ResolveEndpointFailedException: Failed to    resolve endpoint: sql://select%20*%20from%20projects due to: DataSource must be    configured
    at  org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.getEndpoint(DefaultCamelContext.java:587)
    at org.apache.camel.util.CamelContextHelper.getMandatoryEndpoint(CamelContextHelper.java:79)
    at org.apache.camel.model.RouteDefinition.resolveEndpoint(RouteDefinition.java:211)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultRouteContext.resolveEndpoint(DefaultRouteContext.java:107)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultRouteContext.resolveEndpoint(DefaultRouteContext.java:113)
    at org.apache.camel.model.SendDefinition.resolveEndpoint(SendDefinition.java:62)
    at org.apache.camel.model.SendDefinition.createProcessor(SendDefinition.java:56)
    at org.apache.camel.model.ProcessorDefinition.makeProcessorImpl(ProcessorDefinition.java:535)
    at    org.apache.camel.model.ProcessorDefinition.makeProcessor(ProcessorDefinition.java:496)
    at org.apache.camel.model.ProcessorDefinition.addRoutes(ProcessorDefinition.java:220)
    at org.apache.camel.model.RouteDefinition.addRoutes(RouteDefinition.java:1069)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: DataSource must be configured
    at org.apache.camel.component.sql.SqlComponent.createEndpoint(SqlComponent.java:74)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultComponent.createEndpoint(DefaultComponent.java:114)
    at  org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.getEndpoint(DefaultCamelContext.java:5 67)
    ... 22 more
```

I assume that the problem is in my route, but every solution I found give the same result. Any help or advice will be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

You have to configure datasource:

```
from("timer://Timer?period=60000")
.to("sql:select * from projects?dataSource=myDataSource")
.to("stream:out");
```

You can use **sql** component like polling consumer (using of the timer is unnecessary). Some more info can be found here: (http://camel.apache.org/polling-consumer.html)

**UPDATED 1:**

Try to use datasource as shown below:

```
<bean id="myDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
  <property name="driverClassName" value= "oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource" />
  <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:ENETEST" />
  <property name="username" value="System" />
  <property name="password" value="Igor_1" />
  <property name="maxIdle" value="1" />
</bean>
```

Comment: Tx for the replay.  But now I have another error :)  org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Cannot load JDBC driver class 'org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource'
I'm using Maven